# Internal storage

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to store json data I get on the Internet in the **internal storage** of the phone. In order to do so, I have get the data from an API as a string (no issue in this part, nor during the parsing afterwards). Then comes the part where I try to store it in a file... And the problems that come along!

The ultimate goal is to update data when an Internet connection is available, and use the data previously stored when no connection can be found.

Here is my code (data is in the **String *jsonString***):

```
// IN CASE OF INTERNET CONNECTION (ie "jsonString != null")
if (jsonString != null) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(json_InternalFile);
        fos.write(jsonString.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + "File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + "IO Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// IF NO CONNECTION AVAILABLE (ie "jsonString == null)
if (jsonString == null) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(json_InternalFile); 
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString = jsonString + strLine;
        }
        dis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + "File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + "File not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

None of the parts works individually. When I run the app, I got this message: "Unfortunately, the app "APP_NAME" stopped running" (whichever part I comment)

I also tried to replace the line:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(json_InternalFile);
```

with:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(jsonStorage_FileName, 0);
```

... Without success ^^'

I used - and abused ;) - the following code I found:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-internal-external-storage.html

Thank you in advance, I really can't see the problem here (and it's turning me slightly mad ><)

Comment: post your logcat error and code where error is shown.

Comment: Also specify the value of this location variable you are using.

Comment: When doet it crash? At saving or loading? Please tell exact the path in json_InternalFile.

Comment: FileInputStream, DataInputStream, BufferedReader and InputStreamReader to read it back. Why? Look how you write the data: only FileOutputStream. If you use readLine() on one side then i would expect writeLine() at the other side.

Comment: I see now that your code is as in the example. Hmmm. Then show how you initiated json_InternalFile.

Comment: A lot of commenters on that example had the same 'unfortunately' messagge. You are not by chance writing to external storage without permission?

Comment: Thank you guys, I (finally) managed to find the error!
Actually, I forgot to define the **directory** of my internal file (I kinda feel stupid after spending so much time on it ^^'). 

Thanks again!